# Display "published by" before author tag in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, hook

Is there a way to add a filter in functions.php or custom plugin to include a phrase "Published by" before displaying the name of the post author (meta tag) in Wordpress?

Answer (score 0):

Open your functions.php file and paste the codes below:

```
add_filter( 'the_author', 'guest_author_name' );
add_filter( 'get_the_author_display_name', 'guest_author_name' );
 
function guest_author_name( $name ) {

global $post;
$author = 'Published by '.$name;
 
return $name;

}
```